# How to decorate ranges in MS-Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am building a Word Add-in which scans the document for misplaced words. It works like a spell checker by using a dictionary. The spell checker in Word places a curly red line beneath the word and I want to decorate my misplaced words in the same way or by a customized symbol placed on the actual word in the document window.

How can I do that? Where to find documentation on the issue?

It is very important that this decoration don't change the actual document, so "highlight","Bold" or "italics" is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked the same question in a Microsoft forum. And the answer from MS officials is that it isn't possible.